# Sending screen feed as camera output?

Tags: video, skype, webcam, chat, feed

Basically I'm looking for a way to send my screen feed over a video chat rather than the webcam feed itself.

For Example:

During a Skype Video Call, I would be showing the other party a realtime feed from my screen while I talked to them and walked them through what I was doing.

I know there is third party software that can do this, but I was wondering if there was a way to send the screen through Skype, or a similar video chat client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can do it with Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/allfeatures/screensharing/), but I think you need the latest version.